Is there a secret at this weird location at the top of Hebra Mountain?
At the top of Hebra Mountain there's a location with an elevated section of ground, which has two icicles in front of it (pictured below). This area just screams secret to me, yet I can't seem to find anything here. I've tried looking around online, but alas, my google-fu is failing me.

Is there a secret at this location at the top of Hebra Mountain, and if so, how do I earn its reward (and what is the reward)?

You know that you are a gamer when a random area screams secret.

It's a location related to a quest you get from Condè:

You need to bring a snowball that glitters to a specific spot


Which is then revealed to be that pedestal:


Reward is a Heart Piece
